# Use getBulkProperties2 within userFunction to speed up performance

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am currently querying the property database through `getBulkProperties2`. The IDs for this query I get from executing a `userFunction` through `executeUserFunction` that runs `bruteForceFind` on the db.

The `getBulkProperties2` call takes about 40-50 seconds on some slower laptops within our company. The whole Vue app and UI freezes, due to the nature of single-threaded JS. I have tried to move the bulk call to a WebWorker, but you can't pass a model to the WebWorker because the model object references itself, and therefore can't be serialized (circular reference).

The ideal solution would be executing a bulk call within a `userFunction`, as it is executed on a WebWorker by design. I don't see a way in the documentation (or the source code that I decompiled) to do something like this.

What is the recommended way to execute a bulk call within a `userFunction`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `pdb.getObjectProperties` within the `userFunction`. See https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/globals/PropertyDatabase/#getobjectproperties-dbid-propfilter-ignorehidden-propignored

```js
const ignoreHidden = false;
pdb.getObjectProperties( dbId, ['myAttributeName'], ignoreHidden );
```